# SQL query to create a result that represents history

Tags: sql

Imagine if I have a table with "products" and each product has a "price". However, each time the price of a product changes, then this change is recorded in an "old_prices" table.

products table:

```
id: int
name: string
price: int
```

old_prices table:

```
product_id: int
price: int
created_at: int
```

Imagine that there is a product that has had a few prices changes over time. What I want to accomplish is a list that includes the products current price as well as the product's price history. Something like this:

```
id    name      price     time
1     Shampoo   500       01/01/2000
1     Shampoo   550       06/01/2000
1     Shampoo   700       04/03/2001   <- current price!
```

Comment: so what is your question actually

Comment: Are you familiar with joins?

Comment: which db you are using ???

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin You're correct. My question was missing a vital bit of info. The list also has to include the products current price...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a UNION:

```
select  id, name, price, time 
from products 
union 
select  id, name, price, time 
from old_prices 
order by id, time
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? I assume `created_at` column is of datetime data type not int (as said in your original post)

```
select id, name, price, time='Current'
from products
union 
select p.id, p.name, op.price, time=convert(varchar(30), created_at, 120)
from products p
inner join old_prices op
on op.product_id = p.id
```

Comment: The `created_at` is simply seconds since EPOCH, but doesn't really matter. It's `union` that I was looking for.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use can inner join for relate  the tables  and order by

```
select  id, name, price,  null  
from products 
union   
select  a.id, a.name, b.price, b.time 
from products a 
inner join  old_prices b on a.id = b.product_id
order by  a.id, a.name, time
```

Comment: But that doesn't include the product current price from the `products` table, correct?

Comment: @Luke  correct answer  updated .. added  union all for get also the actual price  .